# Dev Demon Form - Missing Data.(MISSING_FORM_DATA)

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-forms

I've recently moved a site to a new sever and I'm getting a strange error message on the forms page.  The site is using EE 2.5.5 and Dev Demon forms 3.1.2.  When I try and submit a form I get the following message:

**The form you submitted contained the following errors**

Missing Data.(MISSING_FORM_DATA)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, the second part is clear; something is either old or out-of-date. I just checked a EE 2.5.5 install, and the `exp_security_hashes` table definitely doesn't have that column, nor any of those columns, in it's table conformation. In 2.5.5, that table looks like this:

```
Field           - Type 
------------------------------------
hash_id         - int(10) unsigned  
date            - int(10) unsigned  
session_id      - varchar(40)       
hash            - varchar(40)
```

What is that third-party folder? `/third-party/forms/`? Is that DevDemon Forms? And did you update anything recently? If it was working before, it still should, but I have noticed some of DevDemon's stuff out of date, but that is usually only a concern if you upgraded EE. I would triple check the settings for that addon, as well as all of your site settings. Make sure you check in your `/system/expressionengine/config/config.php` file as well as your `index.php` file for any possible `$config` overrides that exists somewhere.

Another big trip up: what's your new environment like? Did you jump a bunch of subversions in PHP?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.  The site was originally running 2.5.3, but there was an error with playay and the version of PHP on the server.  So we upgraded to 2.5.5.  I was working through your suggestions and I checked Dev Demons change log, version 3.3.0 and above is compatible with EE 2.5.4 and above.  I've updated Forms to 3.3.1 and looks to be working ok